# Making UILabel font of style bold and italic in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift3, uifont

I am working in swift 3.0 and as per requirement I want to make UILabel text Bold and Italic. For that I written following code.

```
extension UIFont {
    func withTraits(traits:UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits) -> UIFont {
        let descriptor = fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(traits)
        return UIFont(descriptor: descriptor!, size: 0) //size 0 means keep size as it is
    }
    func bold() -> UIFont {
        return withTraits(traits: .traitBold)
    }

    func italic() -> UIFont {
        return withTraits(traits: .traitItalic)
    }
}
```

But in this code value of "descriptor" return nil value. So, ultimately not able to convert the text in bold or italic format.

Any help would be appriciable.

Comment: Check is there `Italic` and `Bold` font available for that `UIFont` of your Label.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the font you want to change supports those traits.. since some of the font only support regular and some only regular, bold, italic, bold italic. If you try those traits with the system font, it will return those traits since the system font supports them.